# Less screenwaste in Gnome titlebars

Tags: gnome, 15.04, ubuntu-gnome

Is there a way to have the closing window icons on the same lines as the menu icons in Gnome?

[image]

Comment: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/53493/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-title-bar-for-firefox-31-gnome-desktop/

Comment: Thanks, but not quite.